# Getting distinct Values from XML in java, OSB, XQuery

Tags: java, xml, xquery, osb, oracle-service-bus

```
<data>  
  <info>  
    <name>A</name>  
  </info>  
  <info>  
    <name>B</name>  
  </info>  
  <info>  
    <name>A</name>  
  </info>  
<info>  
    <name>C</name>  
  </info>  
<info>  
    <name>B</name>  
  </info>  
</info>
```

Is there any way to get result like  in java or OSB or in Xquery
distinct-values is not working in Oracle service bus so i want made java method to get unique names

```
<data>  
<info>  
<name>A</name>  
</info>  
<info>  
<name>B</name>  
</info>   
<info>  
<name>C</name>  
</info>  
</data>
```

Comment: What have you already tried? Please show some code. How do you want to execute XQuery? As you already mention `distinct-values`, this is pretty much it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have solved like this

```
<CUSTOMER_NO_1>{ 
    (for $test in fn:distinct-values($data_ENV1/ns0:data/ns0:CUST/ns0:CUSTNO)
        return $test)[1]
}</CUSTOMER_NO_1>
<CUSTOMER_NO_2>{    
    (for $test in fn:distinct-values($data_ENV1/ns0:data/ns0:CUST/ns0:CUSTNO)
        return $test)[2]
}</CUSTOMER_NO_2>
<CUSTOMER_NO_3>{    
    (for $test in fn:distinct-values($data_ENV1/ns0:data/ns0:CUST/ns0:CUSTNO)
        return $test)[3]
}</CUSTOMER_NO_3>
<CUSTOMER_NO_4>{    
    (for $test in fn:distinct-values($data_ENV1/ns0:data/ns0:CUST/ns0:CUSTNO)
        return $test)[4]
}</CUSTOMER_NO_4>
<CUSTOMER_NO_5>{    
    (for $test in fn:distinct-values($data_ENV1/ns0:data/ns0:CUST/ns0:CUSTNO)
        return $test)[5]
}</CUSTOMER_NO_5>
<CUSTOMER_NO_6>{    
    (for $test in fn:distinct-values($data_ENV1/ns0:data/ns0:CUST/ns0:CUSTNO)
        return $test)[6]
}</CUSTOMER_NO_6>
<CUSTOMER_NO_7>{    
    (for $test in fn:distinct-values($data_ENV1/ns0:data/ns0:CUST/ns0:CUSTNO)
        return $test)[7]
}</CUSTOMER_NO_7>
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume you want to group all the info elements based on the name value and output only one info from each group?

```
let $data :=
<data>  
  <info>  
    <name>A</name>  
  </info>  
  <info>  
    <name>B</name>  
  </info>  
  <info>  
    <name>A</name>  
  </info>  
  <info>  
    <name>C</name>  
  </info>  
  <info>  
    <name>B</name>  
  </info>  
</data>  
return
  <data>{
    let $distinct-names := distinct-values($data/info/name)
    for $name in $distinct-names
    let $infos := $data/info[name eq $name]
    return
      $infos[1]
  }</data>
```

I think you can also use the "group by" extension:

```
let $data :=
<data>  
  <info>  
    <name>A</name>  
  </info>  
  <info>  
    <name>B</name>  
  </info>  
  <info>  
    <name>A</name>  
  </info>  
  <info>  
    <name>C</name>  
  </info>  
  <info>  
    <name>B</name>  
  </info>  
</data>  
return
  <data>{
    for $info in $data/info
    group $info as $infos by $info/name as $name
    return 
      $infos[1]
  }</data>
```

Both of the above queries return:

```
<data>
  <info><name>A</name></info>
  <info><name>B</name></info>
  <info><name>C</name></info>
</data>
```

Comment: `group by` requires XQuery 3.0, which is afaik not supported by Oracle. Using `distinct-values` is fine though.

Comment: Jens Erat - you are correct that OSB does not yet support XQuery 3.0.  However, the group by used in my example is not the standard group by clause, it is the Oracle/BEA group by extension.  Either query should work. See: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13162_01/odsi/docs10gr3/xquery/extensions.html#wp1276960

Comment: But i don't have distinct-values. is group by perfect or not ?

Comment: And can it run if i have following         
<data> 
<info> 
<name>A</name> 
<age>11</age>
</info> 
<info> 
<name>B</name> 
<age>12</age>
</info> 
<info> 
<name>A</name> 
<age>11</age>
</info> 
<info> 
<name>C</name> 
<age>13</age>
</info> 
<info> 
<name>B</name> 
<age>12</age>
</info> 
<class>O-level</class>
</data> 

result should be as

<data> 
<info> 
<name>A</name> 
<age>11</age>
</info> 
<info> 
<name>B</name> 
<age>12</age>
</info> 
<info> 
<name>C</name> 
<age>13</age>
</info> 
<class>O-level</class>
</data>

Comment: I would expect that you *do* have distinct-values if you are using OSB.  So, what do you want to happen if two info elements have the same name but different age values?  Do both or just one show up in the result? e.g.  <data><info><name>A</name><age>1</age></info><info><name>A</name><age>2</age></info></data>

Comment: i want do both name and age in info but name should be unique. if name comes 2nd time whole info tag should remove ..